# Delegation in Sharepoint 2016 - permission conflict?

Tags: sharepoint-server, approval-process

There is an option within SharePoint which allows you to delegate the approval task to somebody else instead. However, I assumed that as soon as you delegate the task to somebody else > they will get temp. approval rights to act upon the request but my assumption seems to be wrong, correct me if otherwise.

I thought the purpose of delegating to another user is so they can act upon the request however the delegated person is not able to approve it due to permissions.

What is the point of the delegation then ??? 
I am confused .... please advise.